# Trying a write a simple program and keep getting this error

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

Error : TemplateDoesNotExist at /1

forms.py

```
class SpotifyForm(forms.Form):
    SpotifyForm = forms.CharField(label= "Spotify Form")
```

views.py

```
  from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
  from django.shortcuts import render
  from django.views import View
  from .forms import SpotifyForm
  from .api import SpotifyAPI
  from  .forms import ClientId
class Search(View):
   form = SpotifyForm
   initial = {"initial" : "Error"}
   template_name = "homepage.html"
   context = {"form": form}

  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form(initial = self.initial)
    return render(request , self.template_name, self.context)
```

urls.py

```
  from django.urls import path
  from .views import Search

  urlpatterns = [
  path("1" , Search.as_view())
  ]
```

templates directory: spotify_client\spotify_calls\spotify_calls\templates

urls.py

```
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.urls import include, path

 urlpatterns = [
 path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
 path("" , include("spotify_calls.urls"))
 ]
```

Basically, all I am doing is trying to access the Spotify API in the views.py(not done yet), just wanted to render the html to at least see if the form will show but nothing did. Also, all recommendations with class based views will be appreciated since this is my first time

Comment: So, do you actually have a `homepage.html` in that templates directory?

Comment: Yes I do have one there.

Comment: Try to put it there directly, editor should show you if it is incorrect path. ```render(request , "homepage.html", self.context)```, try to change it to: ```render(request , "spotify_calls/homepage.html", self.context)```

Answer (score 0):

according to the Django docs :

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from .forms import MyForm

class MyFormView(View):
    form_class = MyForm
    initial = {'key': 'value'}
    template_name = 'form_template.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # <process form cleaned data>
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```